# redis-py - ConnectionError: Socket closed on remote end - overload?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I'm using Redis from Python via redis-py to store JSON in a sorted set.

Everything works fine until I try to get a certain amount of data out of Redis.

---

```
redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=12) 
redis_client.zrange('key', 0, 20, 'desc')
```

Will work fine as I'm only requesting 20 entries.

As soon as I try anything above 35 I get:

```
ConnectionError: Socket closed on remote end
```

I've tried working around it by "chunking" the queries in sets of 5 but it seems that I'm hitting Redis so fast with a lot of queries of 5 that this can still cause the exception.

Am I somehow DDOSing redis?

---

I've tried it on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Last week I actually got away with up to 100 entries at once and chunking worked if I did it in groups of 10, but it seems since then my Redis server has gotten even more sensitive.

---

Here is a little script that reproduces the error.

```
import redis
import ujson as json

r = redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=12)
dummy_json = {"data":"hfoiashflkasdjaisdäjpagufeiaghaifhaspdas", 
          "more": "sdasdpjapsfdjapsofjaspofjsapojfpoasjfpoajfp",
          "more1": "sdasdpjapsfdjapsofjaspofjsapojfpoasjfpoajfp",
          "more2": "sdasdpjapsfdjapsofjaspofjsapojfpoasjfpoajfp",
          "more3": "sdasdpjapsfdjapsofjaspofjsapojfpoasjfpoajfp",
          "more4": "sdasdpjapsfdjapsofjaspofjsapojfpoasjfpoajfp"}

for score in xrange(0, 6000):
    dummy_json["score"]=score
    r.zadd("test", score, json.dumps(dummy_json))

result = r.zrange('test', 0, 200, 'desc')
print result
```

You'll see that if you make `dummy_json` hold less data or request fewer entries at once the exception will be gone.

Comment: Your code works fine on my redis 2.6.16 installatoin with default redis config. It also works for larger entries up to 12000, i.e. `r.zrange('test', 0, 12000, 'desc')`. Does your config differ from the default one?

Comment: Not that I know of. I installed it and that's it. Any specific settings you'd look at ?

Comment: timeout, tcp-keepalive, replication settings - anything that affects network or server load. Is your redis server under load during your test, or is is dedicated to your testing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I completely purged redis and reinstalled -> error is gone. 
I must have change the config at some sleep deprived point. Thanks !